# @Afterreturning advice from Spring AOP doesn't work when I bind returning result to it

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Here's advice

```
@AfterReturning(
        pointcut = "execution(public java.util.List<me.mikholskiy.domains.Customer> me.mikholskiy.daos.CustomerDao.getAll())",
        returning = "resultList")
public void adviceBeforeGetAllCustomersFromDatabase(JoinPoint joinPoint,
                                                    List<Customer> resultList) {
    // ... 
}
```

So when I use this advice annotation without `returning` parameter, it works as expected. But when I want to bind returning result to this advice nothing happens. It doesn't even executed.

Here's target method for this advice:

```
@Override
public List<Customer> getAll() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class)
        .list();
}
```

I use this dependencies

```
org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.3.17
org.springframework:spring-aspects:5.3.17
org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7
```

Comment: Could you try replacing `List<Customer> resultList` with `Object resultList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to match type `List<Customer>` because **`returning`** clause also **restricts matching** to only those method executions that return a value of the specified type *(`Object` or it’s subtypes in this case, which will match any return value)*.

So, in your code, instead of:

```java
public void adviceBeforeGetAllCustomersFromDatabase(
    JoinPoint joinPoint, List<Customer> resultList) {
...
```

Try with:

```java
public void adviceBeforeGetAllCustomersFromDatabase(
    JoinPoint joinPoint, Object resultList) {
...
```

Comment: It also would work with `List<?>`

Comment: Yes actually it will work with `List<Customer>` if it can match but it doesn't, you have to debug it.

Comment: This is not necessary and overkill. For me the example works as shown in the question, there was no need to change anything. And if you do want to make the pointcut more generic, use generic `List`s in the pointcut and/or the method parameter. But like I said, it works just as shown here. Using `Object` is not necessary. I am even using older versions of Spring WebMVC and Spring AOP (both 5.3.12, imported by Boot 2.5.6) in my playground project. Even if I upgrade to latest Boot 2.6.4 and the libraries are bumped to 5.3.16, it still works.

Comment: So even though accepted, this is **not** the solution, it is only a bad workaround. @toiapp, please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub and let me have a look for the real root cause. Something is probably different from what you showed us here, or some information is missing. Maybe you have a typo in the pointcut and a real package name is different from the one in the pointcut or whatever. But this should work without using `Object`.